# Open external App from React native App ( Button Click)

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I want to open New React native App by clicking on Button in which I have used

**Linking Concepts in React native**

**React native  Code : Test is the name of the Other App**

```
Linking.openURL('Test://app');
```

Also following URL for adding Intent in the android.manifest.xml file 
[Andriod Intent](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking#adding-filters)

**Code : Android.manifestfile.xml**

```
  <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
              <category android:name="com.Test" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
              <data android:scheme="Test" android:host="app" />
          </intent-filter>
      </activity>
```

How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: I think good is fine . Did you make a build after implement this code .

Comment: Yes i have done the build but It gives me error (no activity found to handle intent act=android.intent.action.view in react native)

Comment: I Hope you have react-native apps.  
from A app you want to  open B app. right 

In a app  use this code Linking.openURL('Test://app'); 

and in B app change Code : Android.manifestfile.xml file. right 
Please clear ..  is i am getting right ?

Comment: I am doing both the thing in the App A only

Comment: Why ? you want to open same application on itself click ?

Comment: I think you are right ( i am getting confuse in this ) I want to open from app A with the button click to the App B. that is all..so where should i put android manifest code in the App B?

Comment: yes. use Linking.openURL('Test://app'); code in app 1 and put android manifest code in the App B
here is the video of deep-linking 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kuvbfFuVmo&t=243s
and please give thumps up if you feel comment is helpful :)

Comment: Let me check the video and will update you

Comment: Nope same error occured this video is linked for opening Url from Mobile browser , but i want it from App to App:(

Comment: wait brother. let me implement it. i will get back to you

Comment: Thanks Bro I 'm waiting your reply..

Comment: Any update on this I am also looking for same please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this code in your AndroidManifest.xml file parallel to current intent filter

```
 <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos” -->
        <data android:scheme="app"
              android:host="testApp" />
    </intent-filter>
```

and run this command `React-native run-android`

Add below code to your react-native file.

```
<Button title="Click me" onPress={ ()=>{ Linking.openURL('app://testApp')}} />
```

**for save the time . You can to both code in same application and same application will be open on button press**

i just try this code and its working for me
let me know if still facing issue (Y)

Comment: Sorry for late replying Anil. Nope its not working, I have applied above code simultaneously. When i clicked on buttoin its reflect and come back to the same place. ( like swipe to the right and same activity has open after that)...

Comment: I have done above code in App B androidmanifesfile.xml in which android:host name would be same as my app folder name (testAppA) and now clicking from testAppA but it won't redirect to that ( testAppB ) Please help click is working but it won't open new react native application .

Comment: If i am using this way of linking URL (Linking.openURL('testAppA://app')) it gives me error for not handling View intent

Comment: can you show me the code of App B androidmanifesfile.xml  and link code of a file please

Comment: Code : folder name (AppFighter) i have written this code on ChrisApp manifest file.
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="app" android:host="appfighter" />
            </intent-filter>
Link to open Chris App (<Button title="Click me" onPress={ ()=>{ Linking.openURL('app://appfighter')}} />)

Comment: code is fine. 
is this code opening the same app on button click ??

Comment: Yeah Now its working fine (error was app name should be in small case letters). Thanks Anil for support

Comment: @anilsidhu how do I find out android:host some external application which I dont have access to? for example, if I want to open Uber, Lyft, Airbnb, booking.com applications using different button clicks.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the external application by using following code

```
Linking.canOpenURL("fb://app").then(supported => {
  if (supported) {
    Linking.openURL("fb://app");
  } else {
    alert('sorry invalid url')
  }
});
```

Comment: it's doesn't work with Google Maps App other apps it's work very well, any idea?

Answer (score -1):

```
<Button title="Click me" onPress={ ()=>{ Linking.openURL('https://google.com')}} />
```

Here is the link you can check :  https://snack.expo.io/rJm_YkqyW

Comment: This link is useful for browser URL, I want to open another App ( React Native) by clicking on the button